# Guarantee T-SQL Stored Procedure INSERTs before SELECT?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that retrieves sensitive information from an SQL Server 2008 database.  I would like to modify the procedure so that any time it is called, it records information about who called it in a separate table.

I thought something like the following would work:

```
declare @account varchar(255);
set @account = (SELECT SYSTEM_USER);

INSERT into AUDIT_LOG(ACCOUNT, TSTAMP)
VALUES(@account, getdate())
;

--Now fetch data
SELECT x,y,z from sensitive_info;
```

My issue is that the client application can issue a call to this stored procedure and get the sensitive information, but *not* commit the connection and the INSERT never occurs!

Is there some way to force the INSERT to happen before the SELECT?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only COMMIT if a transaction has been started.

So you can test for an open transaction first and disallow the read. This will ensure that no transaction is open to be rolled back. I've used XACT_STATE() here

Using SET XACT_ABORT ON and TRY/CATCH too will mean that the INSERT for logging *must* happen too before the read happens. Any errors *at all* on INSERT will go to the CATCH block. So no read and the logging fail can itself be logged too.

So: this is your guarantee of "read only if logged"

Having an explicit transaction doesn't help: the INSERT is an atomic action anyway. And if the called opens a transaction the log entry can be rolled back

```
CREATE PROC getSecretStuff
AS
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
       RAISERRROR ('Call not allowed in an active transaction', 16, 1)

    INSERT into AUDIT_LOG(ACCOUNT, TSTAMP)
    VALUES(SYSTEM_USER, getdate());

    --Now fetch data
    SELECT x,y,z from sensitive_info;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --     error handling etc
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  My particular problem was complicated a bit because I was using Python's adodbapi module as the client, and it automatically started a transaction, but I found a hack to disable it.  Your solution works well, because if the client doesn't play by the rules, the server won't reveal the data.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [build in auditing functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: I had looked at this initially, but it didn't seem like the audit info could be stored in a database table.  I am not sure what the rationale was there, but I don't particularly find groveling over the Windows event log to be much fun.  I might use this in conjunction with another method, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using expicit transactions and doing the select after the commit statement?

Comment: I tried explicit transactions, but I didn't get the results I expected.  I think the sensitive data was still served up, but I will have to go back and verify.

Comment: I double checked-- despite wrapping the INSERT and SELECT in BEGIN TANSACTION / COMMIT TRANSACTION, the row was never inserted when the client didn't commit.  Funny thing is that the table has an identity column, and the next insert into the table *did* skip a number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

On you insert a record in a table you should be albe to get the SCOPE_IDENTITY() of the ast inserted value. Before doing SELECT x,y,z from sensitive_info; you can check if SCOPE_IDENTITY() > 0 then only execute SELECT statement.

Comment: This seemed like a good idea, but I tried it and it didn't work as expected.  If you look at my comments below, it seems like the identity value is being incremented, but the row is just never inserted without an explicit commit by the client.